# What happens if attempting to save more than the allowed number of files to an NTFS volume?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, storage

According to the Wikipedia article for NTFS, the maximum number of files that can be stored within an NTFS volume is 4,294,967,295. If this limit is reached and a user then attempts to save another file to the system, what happens - does the volume essentially become read-only until one or more files are deleted?

Comment: I, it won't be read only as existing files still be editable.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Depends on how the program does the editing. If it tries to save a temp-file, delete the original file, then rename the temp-file to the oriiinal name (which many programs do) it will still fail. In-place editing is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this once many years ago, when I had a unused server with a huge disk to play with for a couple of days, before it was decommissioned. (Windows 2000 or NT4.0, can't recall).

If memory serves you just get a standard "Acces Denied" error when you attempt to create a new file or folder.
It is NOT a "Disk Full" if I remember correctly.